# Receiving -bash: mage: command not found, when trying to start a new Mage AI project on Google's Compute SSH

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, mage

After installing Mage AI with this command:

```
sudo pip3 install mage-ai
```

I keep receiving -bash: mage: command not found, when trying to start a new Mage AI project on Google's Compute SSH.

Can anyone assist me in troubleshooting this error?

I tried this command: `mage start demo_project`

hoping to start a project, but I received an error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, try running `export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"` and then `source ~/.bashrc` because `pip install ...` puts scripts into `~/.local/bin` which is not include in `$PATH` of Debian.